# Data is not saved in excel the first time when button is clicked but saved the second time in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, file, button

I've written a code that accesses an excel file and extracts the data in the excel file into a two dimensional array called "liste". Also it will transfer the user's input from textboxes and comboboxes from the program into the excel file. The problem is is that my program will not transfer the first time the user inputs their desired data , but will transfer it the second time I press the "kaydet" button. I have debugged and checked and the if statements are working fine with the data I have entered but it just doesn't seem to save the first time I click the "kaydet" button. I'm using WinForms in C#

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

```
private void button_kaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        //the text that is obtained from the text boxes and combo boxes.

        string txt_LRU = this.txtbx_LRUno.Text.ToString();
        string txt_yi = this.txtbx_yi.Text.ToString();
        string txt_td = this.cmbx_td.Text.ToString();
        string txt_toptarih = this.dtp_toplanti.Text.ToString();
        string txt_bastarih = this.dtp_bas.Text.ToString();
        string txt_teslimtarih = this.dtp_teslim.Text.ToString();
        string txt_ilgilinot = this.txtbx_ilgiliNot.Text.ToString();
        string txt_acikislem = this.txtbx_acikislem.Text.ToString();
        string txt_referedosya = this.txtbx_referedosya.Text.ToString();
        string txt_parcano = this.txtbx_parcano2.Text.ToString();

        int lru_row = 0;
        int kontrol = 0;

        for (int f = 1; f < row_number + 1; f++)
        {
            //this if statements checks if the user's input already exists in the excel                   file
            if (txt_LRU == liste[f - 1, 1])
            {
                kontrol = 1;
                lru_row = f + 1;
                //when first starting in the liste[0][0] has these indexes,in the excel cells
                //liste[0][0] actually starts at Cell[1][2]

                string hata_mesaji = "LRU " + txt_LRU + " already exists,would you like to update ?";
                DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(hata_mesaji, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
                if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                {


                    //remember that Cell[column][row]

                    sheet1.Cells[2][lru_row] = txt_LRU;
                    sheet1.Cells[3][lru_row] = txt_parcano;
                    sheet1.Cells[4][lru_row] = txt_yi;
                    sheet1.Cells[5][lru_row] = txt_acikislem;
                    sheet1.Cells[7][lru_row] = txt_td;
                    sheet1.Cells[8][lru_row] = txt_toptarih;

                    MessageBox.Show("The data has been updated");

                }

                else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                    MessageBox.Show("The data has not been updated");
            }

        }
            //if there is no existing LRU then save the data into a new row in excel
            if (kontrol == 0)
            {

                int x = row_number + 1;
                string satir_no = x.ToString();
                sheet1.Cells[1][row_number + 2] = satir_no;
                sheet1.Cells[2][row_number + 2] = txt_LRU;
                sheet1.Cells[3][row_number + 2] = txt_parcano;
                sheet1.Cells[4][row_number + 2] = txt_yi;
                sheet1.Cells[5][row_number + 2] = txt_acikislem;
                sheet1.Cells[7][row_number + 2] = txt_td;
                sheet1.Cells[8][row_number + 2] = txt_toptarih;
                sheet1.Cells[9][row_number + 2] = txt_bastarih;
                sheet1.Cells[10][row_number + 2] = txt_teslimtarih;
                sheet1.Cells[11][row_number + 2] = txt_ilgilinot;


            }


        //to save and close the excel file
        uyg.DisplayAlerts = false;
        kitap.Save();
        kitap.Close();
        uyg.DisplayAlerts = true;
        uyg.Quit();

       DialogResult dialogResult2 = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to see the excel        file?", "Bilgilendirme", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult2 == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:\\Users\\casperpc\\Desktop\\hey.xls");

        }
        else if (dialogResult2 == DialogResult.No)
        {

        }
```

}

Comment: Hi, it may sound simple but did you save your Excel document after the update ?

Comment: Yes my program automatically saves the inputs that are transferred to the excel file.I didnt post the whole code maybe because it would be too crowded but I have updated my code now.